# kyverno pods stuck in crashloop

Tags: openshift-4, kyverno

Two of our three Kyverno pods keep getting stuck in crash loops.

State details in ArgoCD are:

```
back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kyverno pod=kyverno-85b8ccfffd-7vb4t_kyverno(cf50fb6d-a1c2-4384-bdbf-bebe865daa73)
```

All I can find in the logs is:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string [recovered]
       panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string

goroutine 2254 [running]:
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime.HandleCrash({0x0, 0x0, 0xc004736140?})
    k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.26.0/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:56 +0xd7
panic({0x2f552e0, 0xc00158ee40})
    runtime/panic.go:884 +0x212
```

which does not clarify a whole lot. How do I resolve this?

Comment: It looks like kyerno is crashing. I would consider opening an issue in https://github.com/kyverno/kyverno/issues, because even if the ultimate cause turns out to be a configuration issue, you should be receiving a useful error message rather than a crash and a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, please do open an issue in the Kyverno GitHub repo and provide reproduction steps including version, K8s platform, etc.